# How to start a timer without page refresh (Rails/JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, timer, stimulusjs

I have a model named 'Deal' which has `start_at` and `end_at` attributes. I have implemented a countdown timer using `hotwire/stimulus` JS.

1. When the deal starts (start date is in the past, end date is in the future), the countdown timer displaying time left to deal will be shown. e.g Time left to deal: 2 hours, 4 minutes, 30 seconds and so on. It will decrement by 1 second.
2. If the deal has not yet started (start date is in the future), the page will show "Deal is going to start on #{datetime}".

However, the user needs to refresh the page they are currently on to see a timer if the deal has started in the meantime (i.e. transitioning from "Deal is going to start on #{datetime}" to a countdown timer). I am wondering what's the best way to start the timer without refreshing the page. Thanks.

Comment: It would he great to add the minimum Controller code you are using. This will make it much easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to manage a 'timer' that runs some function every X milliseconds is via the browser's [`setInterval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

This function can be used like this - `const intervalID = setInterval(myCallback, 500);` - where `myCallback` is the function that will attempt to run every `500`ms.

The timer can be 'cancelled' by calling [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) and giving it the interval ID that is created as the result of `setInterval`.

### Example HTML

- Here we have a basic HTMl structure where we set our controller `timer` and set the from/to times along with targets that hold the messages based on three states.
- These three states are 'before', 'during' (when the current time is between the two times) and 'after'.

```html
<section class="prose m-5">
  <div
    data-controller="timer"
    data-timer-from-value="2022-03-08T10:41:32.111Z"
    data-timer-to-value="2022-03-09T11:10:32.111Z"
  >
    <div style="display: none" data-timer-target="before">
      Deal will start on <time data-timer-target="fromTime"></time>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none" data-timer-target="during">
      Deal is active <time data-timer-target="toTimeRelative"></time>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none" data-timer-target="after">
      Deal ended on <time data-timer-target="toTime"></time>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### Example Stimulus Controller

- This `timerController` accepts the `to` and `from` times as strings (ISO strings are best to use, and remember the nuances of time-zones can be complex).
- When the controller connects we do three things; 1. set up a timer to run `this.update` every X milliseconds and put the timer ID on the class for clearing later as `this._timer`. 2. Set the time values (the inner time labels for messaging). 3. Run the `this.update` method the initial time.
- `this.getTimeData` parses the from/to datetime strings and does some basic validation, it also returns these date objects along with a `status` string which will be one of `BEFORE`/`DURING`/`AFTER`.
- `this.update` - this shows/hides the relevant message parts based on the resolved status.

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

const BEFORE = 'BEFORE';
const DURING = 'DURING';
const AFTER = 'AFTER';

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    interval: { default: 500, type: Number },
    locale: { default: 'en-GB', type: String },
    from: String,
    to: String,
  };

  static targets = [
    'before',
    'during',
    'after',
    'fromTime',
    'toTime',
    'toTimeRelative',
  ];

  connect() {
    this._timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.update();
    }, this.intervalValue);

    this.setTimeValues();
    this.update();
  }

  getTimeData() {
    const from = this.hasFromValue && new Date(this.fromValue);
    const to = this.hasToValue && new Date(this.toValue);

    if (!from || !to) return;
    if (from > to) {
      throw new Error('From time must be after to time.');
    }

    const now = new Date();

    const status = (() => {
      if (now < from) return BEFORE;

      if (now >= from && now <= to) return DURING;

      return AFTER;
    })();

    return { from, to, now, status };
  }

  setTimeValues() {
    const { from, to, now } = this.getTimeData();
    const locale = this.localeValue;

    const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
      dateStyle: 'short',
      timeStyle: 'short',
    });

    this.fromTimeTargets.forEach((element) => {
      element.setAttribute('datetime', from);
      element.innerText = formatter.format(from);
    });

    this.toTimeTargets.forEach((element) => {
      element.setAttribute('datetime', to);
      element.innerText = formatter.format(to);
    });

    const relativeFormatter = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat(locale, {
      numeric: 'auto',
    });

    this.toTimeRelativeTargets.forEach((element) => {
      element.setAttribute('datetime', to);
      element.innerText = relativeFormatter.format(
        Math.round((to - now) / 1000),
        'seconds'
      );
    });
  }

  update() {
    const { status } = this.getTimeData();

    [
      [BEFORE, this.beforeTarget],
      [DURING, this.duringTarget],
      [AFTER, this.afterTarget],
    ].forEach(([key, element]) => {
      if (key === status) {
        element.style.removeProperty('display');
      } else {
        element.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
      }
    });

    this.setTimeValues();

    if (status === AFTER) {
      this.stopTimer();
    }
  }

  stopTimer() {
    const timer = this._timer;

    if (!timer) return;

    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  disconnect() {
    // ensure we clean up so the timer is not running if the element gets removed
    this.stopTimer();
  }
}
```

Comment: actually I want to transition from "deal is going to start on {datetime}"(BEFORE) to "time left to deal: # hours, # minutes, # seconds"(DURING - this decrements by 1 second) without the user needing to refresh the page. What I understand is I need to continue with the timer that runs every X second(in my case 1 second) even when the page loads with the status of BEFORE i.e. deal is not yet open. I initially stopped the timer when the current time < start time as I thought it's not the best solution and an expensive operation.

Comment: @farha - this answer has now been updated, you can format the 'toTimeReleative' any way you want (just defaults to showing seconds in the code above). The key change is the `setTimeValues` method also runs every 'interval' now and the timer will stop when no longer needed.

Comment: Slight nitpick: "will run every 500ms" should be "will attempt to run at most every 500ms". `setInterval`/`setTimeout` will drift over time and isn't really an accurate clock on its own.